# Create AppInsights instance for StaticWebApp via Bicep

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-bicep, azure-static-web-app

In the Azure Portal the Static Web App has a tab to link an Application Insights instance to the Static Web App:
[image]

I'm looking for a way to configure this section via Bicep, but I can't find anything in the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/staticsites?tabs=bicep) about how to configure it.

So my question is how can I link an Application Insights instance to a Static Web App instance via Bicep template?

Comment: If you click on `export template` you should probably find some interesting info. Also on the configuration / app settings section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To link Application Insights instance into Static Web Apps there is ***no default Bicep/ARM template*** available.

We can achieve this by adding **Application Insights Instrumentation key** in your Static Web App **Application Settings**.

Set the `APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY` setting in the config.

Add the child resources of ***Application Insights instrumentation key*** in your Static Web App ***Bicep*** Template.

```json
  resource staticWebAppSettings 'config@2021-01-15' = {
    name: 'appsettings'
    properties: {
      APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY: <your appInsightIntrumentationKey>
    }
  }
```

After Adding above step the Bicep/ARM templates works as expected.

#### Result

[image]
Refer [Github](https://github.com/Azure/static-web-apps/issues/577#issuecomment-916802697)  discussion to Add Application Insights into Static Web Application.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding `hidden-link` tags to the tags of your Azure static web app:

```
var tagsWithHiddenLinks = union({
  'hidden-link: /app-insights-resource-id': appInsightsId
  'hidden-link: /app-insights-instrumentation-key': appInsightsInstrumentationKey
  'hidden-link: /app-insights-conn-string': appInsightsConnectionString
}, tags)

resource staticWebApp 'Microsoft.Web/staticSites@2022-09-01' = {
  name: staticWebAppName
  location: location
  tags: tagsWithHiddenLinks // <--- here
  sku: {
    name: 'Free'
    tier: 'Free'
  }
  properties: {
    // ...
  }
}
```

There's more details in my blog post:

https://johnnyreilly.com/bicep-link-azure-application-insights-to-static-web-apps